# Xamarin ios ZXING scanner not analyzing QR

Tags: ios, xamarin, zxing

i'm using an Iphone 10 with ios 15.3.1,Zxing version = 2.4.1, compiling the xamarin project in windows. I been trying to make a qr scanner with zxing for ios android, but when i run my app in ios, it won't go to the onResult event. I've tried with a lot of methods of doing this, but nothing seems to work. The camera shows, but the result never comes truh. ¿Does someone have any idea why this is happening? I also tried apps from other devs that are using zxing and it also dosen't work. but when i scan with the camera app it works.

```
        async void OnButtonClickedAsync(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var options = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanningOptions
        {
            CameraResolutionSelector = HandleCameraResolutionSelectorDelegate
        };
        MobileBarcodeScanner scanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner();
        //scanner.TopText = "Hold camera up to barcode to scan";
        //scanner.BottomText = "Barcode will automatically scan";
        //scanner.UseCustomOverlay = false;
        scanner.FlashButtonText = "Flash";
        scanner.CancelButtonText = "Cancel";
        
        scanner.Torch(true);
        scanner.AutoFocus();
       
        var result = await scanner.Scan(options);
        HandleScanResult(result);
    }

    void HandleScanResult(ZXing.Result result)
    {
        if (result != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Text))
            scanResultText.Text = result.Text;
            
    }
    CameraResolution HandleCameraResolutionSelectorDelegate(List<CameraResolution> availableResolutions)
    {
        //Don't know if this will ever be null or empty
        if (availableResolutions == null || availableResolutions.Count < 1)
            return new CameraResolution() { Width = 800, Height = 600 };

        //Debugging revealed that the last element in the list
        //expresses the highest resolution. This could probably be more thorough.
        return availableResolutions[availableResolutions.Count - 1];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I compiled using a mac and it worked fine, must be a bug of visual studio on windows.